# MongoDB+PHPでinsert()した後に_idの値を取得する方法

Tags: php, mongodb

UbuntuでMongoDBとPHPを使用しています。

PHPプログラム中にて

```
$doc = array("name" => rand());
$coll->insert( $doc );
```

とした際にどの_idで書き込まれたかわかりません。そのため、updateもdeleteもできません。
insert()した際に、何かしらの方法で_idの値を取得することはできないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_id`の値を見てください。

```
$doc = array("name" => rand());
$coll->insert( $doc );
$id = $doc['_id'];
```